# python install orange, long time and warnings everywhere

Tags: python, orange

How long does python take to install an orange package usually?

It takes more than half an hour for me and it is still building.

plus, I got warnings everywhere about the same thing

```
command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
```

Does anyone can tell me what is happening?
I really need something can work in the machine learning field in python.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Haven't used orange, but what do you want to do? Have you played with scikit-learn? A lot of packages are built from source and do take a while (numpy, pandas, sklearn, etc.)

Comment: It is building several packages from source - compiling c code. Don't worry about the warnings. Are you looking for something simpler to do with machine learning? If you're looking for something that installs more quickly, what features do you need?

Comment: Hi, Kyle and Thomas, I am looking for some well-established machine learning package in python. It is better that it can offer me several algorithms. It is not a problem that it takes long time, I just want to make sure it did not go into somewhere terrible.    I have tried scikit-learn, it does not work on my labtop. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one gives an answer, I think I should summary it myself.
It takes hours, but later, it is perfectly functional.
So, no worries. :-)